# I want to use an if in where clause in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

The following is part of my query
  `where
  if(teler.arrange ="Y",(teler.id_to IN ('1940')),0) GROUP BY`to`,`

How will I have this in a Zend query which is currently like this

`$objSelect->Orwhere('teler.id IN (?))', $where['id']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty straightforward:

```
$objSelect->orWhere('if(teler.arrange ="Y", (teler.id_to IN (?)), 0)', $where['id'])
          ->group('to');
```